# Missing rows due to too strict WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql

In the example code below we have attempted to minimize our problem into a simplified test case.

We have 3 tables: users, images and ratings.

1: We want to print all entries from the ‘ratings’ table.

2: In the ‘images’ table, there can be several images uploaded by the same users into different sections of the site, e.g. ‘user_profile_picture’ or ‘user_cover_photo’.

3: When printing the ratings, we want to fetch entries from the ‘images’ table if the user has uploaded a profile picture (section = ‘profile_picture’).

The WHERE statement in the query in the example code fails for users with no profile pictures uploaded.

How can we make sure to print all entries, as well as only grab the image connected to the user if section = profile_picture …?

```
CREATE TABLE `test_ratings` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rating` enum('1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
INSERT INTO `test_ratings` (`id`, `user_id`, `rating`) VALUES
    (2, 2, '4'),
    (1, 1, '5');
    
CREATE TABLE `test_users` (
    `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
INSERT INTO `test_users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES
    (1, 'Test person 1'),
    (2, 'Test person 2');
    
CREATE TABLE `test_users_images` (
    `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `filename` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    `section` enum('user_cover_photo','user_profile_picture') DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` int(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
INSERT INTO `test_users_images` (`id`, `filename`, `section`, `user_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'rtfos.jpg', 'user_profile_picture', 2),
    (2, 'exer8.jpg', 'user_cover_photo', 2);
    
<?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "website");

   $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT image.filename, user.username, ratings.rating
      FROM test_ratings ratings
      INNER JOIN test_users user ON user.id = ratings.user_id
      INNER JOIN test_users_images image ON image.user_id = user.id
      WHERE image.section = \'user_profile_picture\'');
  
   while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      echo '<p>' . $row->username . ' - ' . $row->filename . '</p>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, or you will lose the ratings where no test_user or test_user_images exist... of course the WHERE condition must be removed as well (because you want to show "all entries from the ratings table"

Comment: If a column is `AutoIncrement` you don't insert a value. Your table definitions don't have any relationships (ie: Foreign Key constraints).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, though the query seems to fail on the WHERE statement. We have tried to change the lines to LEFT JOIN in the test case without success.

Comment: I edited my post... your requirements are ambigous. "print all entries" includes "if section = profile_picture"

Comment: Yes, thanks. If we remove the WHERE condition, we will fetch multiple lines (per photo type) per rating if the user has several photos.
We want to print the ratings and show the username and profile picture connected to the rating. If the user has no photo uploaded, the rating does not print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already commented, start with the user table and left join to it. Include the image section filter in the `ON` clause of the respective join.

```
SELECT image.filename,
       user.username,
       ratings.rating
       FROM test_users user
            LEFT JOIN test_users_images image
                      ON image.user_id = user.id
                         AND image.section = 'user_profile_picture'
            LEFT JOIN test_ratings ratings
                      ON user.id = ratings.user_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=11a87331032c8de5f0128128dd4f3c49)

P.S.: It's a `WHERE` *clause*, not a statement.

Comment: This solved our issue. Thanks a million! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By changing the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN for image.sections you keep all rows from ratings (if the user still exists in the database). To include users without a profile image you have to add a condition that image.section is allowed to be NULL.

```
SELECT image.filename, user.username, ratings.rating
  FROM test_ratings ratings
  INNER JOIN test_users user ON user.id = ratings.user_id
  LEFT JOIN test_users_images image ON image.user_id = user.id
  WHERE image.section = 'user_profile_picture' OR image.section IS NULL
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fdb4b020a06e095d84c705b8150e9859)